# Is there any specific folder for staging area in Git?

Tags: git

According to my understanding, Git working directory is a folder that contains `.git` inside and Git local repository is `.git` folder. I'm wondering, does Git have a specific folder to deal with the **staging area**?

Comment: It's file `.git/index`. See https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/IndexFile, https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/WhatIsTheIndex, https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git.git/tree/Documentation/technical/index-format.txt?id=HEAD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add a file to the index, Git stores the actual contents of the file as an object in the standard place in the repository and updates the index file, `.git/index`, to contain a reference to it.

This design makes committing the state of the index very fast because all the blob objects are already present.  Git need only create the tree and commit objects required for the commit.

There are commands to list the contents of the index to see what's in it, such as `git ls-files -s`, if you're interested.